# Can every lattice polyhedron be subdivided into lattice tetrahedra?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, triangulation

In 2D, every polygon can be triangulated without introducing new vertices. In particular, lattice polygons can be divided into lattice triangles.

In 3D, the [Schönhardt polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron) cannot be triangulated into tetrahedra without adding new vertices. What about the following weaker question?: Can every lattice polyhedron be subdivided into lattice tetrahedra, allowing the introduction of new vertices (as long as they are lattice vertices)?

Comment: Doesn't the example you've already given, the Schönhardt polyhedron, answer your question? Only minimal perturbation is needed to move its vertices to lattice points.

Comment: @RosieF Can you actually move its vertices to lattice points? In such a way that it doesn't contain any lattice points in the interior (otherwise we could use those points in the triangulation)?

Comment: Ah, so introducing new vertices is OK? Sorry, your question's body confused me -- in your first para, then again in your second para's first sentence, you say "without introducing new vertices", so I thought that restriction was relevant to your question.

Comment: @RosieF Right - introducing new vertices is the reason this is a weaker question. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: I feel like you should be able to construct a version of the Schönhardt polyhedron based on the octahedral characterization (treat an octahedron as a triangular biprism and twist the top face) that maintains the property of not being subdividable without containing any lattice points at all; possibly something along the lines of (0,0,0) - (1, 1, 0) - (1, 2, 0) on the bottom face and (-1, 1, 1) - (0, 1, 1) - (1, 0, 1) on the top face. That has no interior lattice vertices, but I haven't sanity-checked its decomposability (or even whether it's non-self-itersecting).

Comment: (Minor correction since I'm outside the edit window: while I said 'biprism' there, I meant 'antiprism'.)